# react-bootstrap toggle/hide navbar with jquery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I've got a [react-bootstrap navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/). And I want to add an extra toggle/hide action to the navbar. (next to the default toggle button). My first approach was the following code.

```
 if ($("#navbar-nav").hasClass("show"))
        $("#navbar-nav").collapse("hide")
```

But this only works half. Since I can run it. It will indeed hide the collapse. But when I toggle it after this the original toggle button it won't run the first time. Only after pressing the second time it will show it again.
I guess the the bootstrap js code conflicts with the react-bootstrap code. (not setting a new state?)

**So, my question would be:** How can I toggle or hide the react-bootstrap navbar collapse with jQuery or React?

## ---UPDATE----

I've added more code for a better picture.

This is part of the Navbar Functional Component

```
  return (
    <Navbar
      expand="lg"
      sticky="top"
      className={"align-self-center"}
    >
      <Row className={"m-0"} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Col xs={6} lg={0} className={"d-lg-none align-self-center"}>
          <Navbar.Toggle  // <---------------------------- TOGGLE
            id={"navbar"}
            aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"
            className={"float-right align-self-center"}
          >
            {<GiHamburgerMenu />}
          </Navbar.Toggle>
        </Col>

        <Col xs={12} lg={9} className={"align-self-center"}>
          <Navbar.Collapse // <---------------------------- COLLAPSE
            id="navbar-nav"
            className={"justify-content-end "}
          >
            <MenuHeader data={data} />
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Navbar>
  )
```

The menu has an item with class `.contact-button` If it is clicked it will run the following code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    $(".contact-button").click(function() { 
      if ($("#navbar-nav").hasClass("show")) // <----------- if is currently showing  
        $("#navbar-nav").collapse("hide") // <----------- toggle 
      
      var $target = $("html,body")
      $target.animate({ scrollTop: $target.height() }, 500)
    })
  }, [])
```

These are two uses of the contact button. A simplified rendered html output of the button. The li element is a child of the `<MenuHeader/>`

```
<div class="btn contact-button">contact</div>
<li class="nav-item contact-button">contact</li>
```

Comment: React's main purpose is for presentational DOM manipulation.  Show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: @larz, yes. I've added more code on how I currently have it

Comment: Good start.  That `useEffect` will only fire once when the component mounts as shown in your current code.  Will you please add the code for the button you're referring to as well?

Comment: @larz the button is used twice. once in the navbar menu and once as a CTA button. The simple html output is shown above now.

Comment: I don't see any `onClick` handlers.

Comment: it is not ran from the same component. That's why I've added jQuery and based on the className I've used a `.click()` method to run the script. `$(".contact-button").click(function() { `

Comment: Two thoughts - 
1 - what is the point of using React if you're going to convolute things with jquery?
2 - In order for anyone on here to help you, you must show us the entire code in question.

Comment: Can I call, check and update the current state of the navbar toggle maybe? I'm too new with this to know where it is stored in `<Navbar.Toggle/>`

Comment: as response to two comments up. (posts crossed) The jQuery is my sloppy attempt to influence the `<navbar/>` component.I thought there would be a `.collapse()` method, like in the traditional BS. And I think the complete code it shown in part one. But maybe I have to change my question to something like. `How can I influence the toggle state, other than using <Navbar.Toggle/>` I can't find (or don't know how to) the answer docs. Maybe I should go for a different react-bs library. One that can override what stores the state.